# Subtracting two datetime values

Tags: sql, authentication, logout

I'm trying to get the length of time a user was logged in for. My code is grabbing the login and logout time but the `loginLength` field in my DB table isn't updating with this code. Any ideas what's wrong with it?

```
$logout = "UPDATE Emp
           SET loginStatus = 0,
           LogoutTime = NOW()
           WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";
if (! mysql_query($logout))
        {
        echo "Error" . mysql_error();
        }          
$time = "UPDATE Emp 
         SET loginLength = DATEDIFF(milliseconds,LoginTime,LogoutTime)
         WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]'";
         if (! mysql_query($time))
        {
        echo "Error" . mysql_error();
        }
```

Comment: You'd better specify dbms here, because many products do date/time things their in own ways instead of as specified by ANSI/ISO SQL.

Comment: I'm using Parallels Plesk

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using MySQL as your database (the obsolete "mysql_" functions are a hint).  You are then using SQL Server syntax for the date operations.

The MySQL equivalent is:

```
UPDATE Emp 
     SET loginLength = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, LoginTime, LogoutTime) / 1000
     WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]';
```

You can try "MILLISECOND", but it is not documented as working.